# What to do if Drupal seems not to connect with outside?

Tags: ubuntu, drupal-7

Today, out of the blue, my drupal 7 website began to show the message:

```
Unable to connect with the reCAPTCHA server (www.google.com): 110: Connection timed out
```

In log error, i found out that gives error also for sending confirmation mail for new accounts and that i'm not able anymore to get long term access token from facebook from facebook wall module. It seems like drupal can't connect to outside world... Any clue, i don't see, about what is going on?

The ubuntu server of the site is up and running, the site is reachable.

Comment: maybe it's an issue related to facebook api changes, when was the last time it was working fine?

Comment: It's not only facebook. Smtp is not responding and recaptcha too

Comment: are you using proxy server?

Comment: no. The issue showed up, out of the blue, all was running till yesterday

Comment: did you check admin/reports/status ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the connection failed for a problem with ipv6. For some reason they were reachable very slowly.
I did

```
telnet google.it 80
```

and found out that the reply

```
1) Trying 2a00:1450:4007:80e::2003...
2) Trying 216.58.208.227... 
3) Connected to google.it.
4) Escape character is '^]'.
```

took 1 minute to pass from line 1 to line 2. So i disabled ipv6 on my box adding these lines to /etc/sysctl.conf

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1 
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1 
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

and restart sysctl

```
sudo sysctl -p
```

and all problems were gone.